# scandit not scanning 2D-codes

Tags: codenameone

I've been trying use Scandit in Codename One through their library. I can display the camera screen on my phone and also scan barcodes, but not 2D codes. I'm using version 5.5.2 for both Android and IOS.

I've read on their site that you have to enable the scanning of 2D codes so I went to check if I could change anything in the Native Interface or maybe use an implemented function to enable the correct Symbologies.

**My question is**, is it possible to enable these symbologies in their library. Should this be enabled automatically? How can I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code that we need to add to enable it in iOS/Android?

Comment: Android: https://support.scandit.com/hc/en-us/articles/207162529-Barcode-does-not-scan

IOS: https://support.scandit.com/hc/en-us/articles/205544122-Barcode-does-not-scan

Answer (score 1):

The [Scandit docs](https://support.scandit.com/hc/en-us/articles/207162529-Barcode-does-not-scan) example for 2d bar codes uses the `SYMBOLOGY_EAN13` and `SYMBOLOGY_CODE128` symbologies.

In the Codename One API, that translates to something like:

```
Collection<Integer> symbologies = CodeScanner.createSymbologySet(
    CodeScanner.SYMBOLOGY_EAN13,
    CodeScanner.SYMBOLOGY_CODE128
);
CodeScanner.getInstance().scan(symbologies, new ScanResult() {
    ...
});
```

Check out the [CodeScanner](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit/blob/master/src/com/codename1/scandit/CodeScanner.java#L343) source for some more details on available symbology constants.

Comment: I did use that to create the symbology list, but it doesn't scan the 2D barcodes. In the scandit example, they set the usage of the codes to true. I don't see that part in the code you posted. Does it happen interally in your library?

Comment: Barcode scanning works fine with that method. That's why I suspect that either the trial doesn't support the Professional or Entreprise edition (which it seems to do) or, the 2D codes are still not enabled even though you put them in the Collection.

Comment: The Scandit document we are referencing seems to have disappeared.  https://support.scandit.com/hc/en-us/articles/207162529-Barcode-does-not-scan  I don't see any setting, other than the ones we are already using, to "enable 2d barcode scanning".  It could be that the barcodes you are trying to scan use a different symbology than the ones you are trying out.  They have a long list of supported symbologies.  See the constants at https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit/blob/master/src/com/codename1/scandit/CodeScanner.java

Comment: I've been trying to scan multiple 2D codes and it turns out some are scanable like CODABAR and AZTEC. The one I need is a GS1 Datamatrix which doesn't scan sadly. I added every option to the Symbology collection. At this point, I don't really know what the issue could be. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: That's good to hear.  Can you share the solution for the benefit of those that may stumble across this thread later?

Comment: To be honest, it already worked, but the 2D codes really take a while to scan. They scan better on paper and when you film them from a certain distance. Also, you have a symbology named "SYMBOLOGY_UNKNOWN" which makes the app crash on my phone.